# Create a SOAP message with Assertion Saml2 in Header with c# code

Tags: c#, wcf, saml-2.0

I have a Government Web Server with an exposed service that I need to consume.
So far, for other services of the same Web Server I have done this:
I created a CustomBinding, which creates a Header with only the Security tag. This is the code:

```
 var sec = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement(
            new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never),
new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient));
sec.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
sec.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
sec.IncludeTimestamp = true;
sec.SetKeyDerivation(false);
sec.KeyEntropyMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityKeyEntropyMode.ServerEntropy;
sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;              

CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();

myBinding.Elements.Add(sec);
myBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
myBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
```

This is the result obtained by the CustomBinding();

```
<s:Header><VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPowknFB+N96ZEtO/wdI2E9acAAAAAcJdp/1Hm1EmYTKrs1mDzIDxAUSKqP+BEuW7DUbd1RNIACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-a770c99d-342d-4dea-8b28-271df0df9703-1">
        <u:Created>2020-11-14T09:48:00.479Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2020-11-14T09:53:00.479Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-7f91b027-5e8e-49e2-a949-9dc6a0401d65-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">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
</o:BinarySecurityToken>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <Reference URI="#uuid-a770c99d-342d-4dea-8b28-271df0df9703-1">
        <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <DigestValue>43xZllvfRz3QmOcPI2oMopJ6Z0U=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>hA6yVephrqRX1U0w==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
        <o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-7f91b027-5e8e-49e2-a949-9dc6a0401d65-2"/></o:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

As they asked me to insert the Assertion Header Security tag before the Header, I created one like this:

```
Saml2Assertion oAssertion = new Saml2Assertion(new Saml2NameIdentifier("MY"));
oAssertion.Subject = new Saml2Subject(new Saml2NameIdentifier("ident"));
Saml2Conditions asCondition = new Saml2Conditions();
asCondition.NotBefore = DateTime.Now;
asCondition.NotOnOrAfter = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
oAssertion.Conditions = asCondition;
Saml2AuthenticationStatement asAuthnStatement = new Saml2AuthenticationStatement(new Saml2AuthenticationContext());
oAssertion.Statements.Add(asAuthnStatement);
```

What I would like to do, using C # code, is to insert the Assertion created in the Header, for example like this:

```
myBinding.Elements.Add(oAssertion);//Obviously this is an example that cannot work!
```

At the end of it all I would like to get a Request like this (The body is already created by calling the Wsdl class):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" saml:ID="identity-assertion" saml:IssueInstant="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100" saml:Version="2.0" wsu:Id="identity-assertion" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd">
        <saml:Issuer>Company</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID>02942630753</saml:NameID>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T13:03:19.885+0100"/>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextDecl/>
                <saml:AuthenticatingAuthority/>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement/>
    </saml:Assertion>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" saml:ID="authorization-assertion" saml:IssueInstant="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100" saml:Version="2.0" wsu:Id="authorization-assertion" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd">
        <saml:Issuer/>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID>02942630753</saml:NameID>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T13:03:19.885+0100"/>
        <saml:AuthzDecisionStatement Decision="Permit" Resource="https://wsit-virtasl.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it:8181/aslba/IDocumentService">
            <saml:Action Namespace="http://www.sist.puglia.it/Schemas/PDD_SIST/SCATEL/FSE/">addDocument</saml:Action>
        </saml:AuthzDecisionStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement/>
    </saml:Assertion>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" saml:ID="applicative-assertion" saml:IssueInstant="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100" saml:Version="2.0" wsu:Id="applicative-assertion" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd">
        <saml:Issuer>Company</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID>02942630753</saml:NameID>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T13:03:19.885+0100"/>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-18T13:03:19.885+0100">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextDecl/>
                <saml:AuthenticatingAuthority/>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:sist:1.0:subject:subject-application-id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">APPNAME</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:sist:1.0:subject:subject-application-vendor" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CODICES</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:sist:1.0:subject:subject-application-version" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">5</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:sist:1.0:subject:subject-application-nonce" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Lz40oj9kDP8pvM2EFdbk</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:sist:1.0:subject:subject-application-digest" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">FjZuq3R5dkXIpAUL4+a2g0UGS/E=</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:sist:1.0:subject:subject-application-created" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">2018-12-19T13:03:19.886</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CLRERT68P01T556Y</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">C</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">02942630753</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:subject:role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">RIS000055</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xspa:1.0:subject:organization-id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">160000</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xspa:1.0:subject:organization" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">SOFTWARE HOUSE EMITTENTE</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xspa:1.0:resource:patient:consent" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">true</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xspa:1.0:resource:patient:hl7:confidentiality-code" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">false</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:xspa:1.0:environment:locality" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">160000-SOFTWARE HOUSE EMITTENTE</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.openweb.com/Schemas/PDD_SIST/FSE/addDocument</Action>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:556111ac-162d-4b27-8140-b5f558ff14b9</MessageID>
    <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://wsit-vrt.com:8081/DcSrv</To>
    <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
    </ReplyTo>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <addDocument xmlns="http://www.openweb.com/Schemas/PDD_SIST/FSE/">
        <document>
            <document>++++++++++PC9hZG1pbmlzdHJhdGl2ZUdlbmRlYisbYxktjFzkfSLJiRYExMeKA46kAAAAAAAA=</document>
            <documentName>documentname</documentName>
            <status>Approved</status>
            <binaryDocument>++//3fuacM//YFIq7HgX/+13dQhABsdXTVCRDFFOTg0Pl0KICAvU2l6ZSAzMjgKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjEwMzI2MgolJUVPRgo=</binaryDocument>
            <binaryName>filename.pdf</binaryName>
        </document>
    </addDocument>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I accomplish this, using the c# code? Am I getting the approach wrong?
I have seen that others have the same problem as me, with my own Web Service, but I have not found any valid solution. Thank you all.

Comment: You can refer to the official documentation: SAML Token Provider(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/saml-token-provider) to insert assertion header.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader()
```